# how to verify linux server security vulnerability?

Tags: security, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'd just install RHEL7, how do i certify that my server is free from vulnerability, virus or malware?, is the any tools or script that i can use to verify it?

tq
regards
adabi

Comment: Are you talking about the integrity of the OS download, or the state of a running system? no, there is no conceivable way to vet everything about a modern OS's running state. There are some conceptual models that allow the mathematical verification of the conceptual OS, but Linux is not one of them. In practical terms, you can check for known signs of intrusion, or verify the integrity of a given resource, but you can never be certain that any machine is totally clean. also, every computer has vulnerabilities, many of which are unknown by even the program authors. all you can do is patch.

Comment: previously my server was on rhel6.5 and it was attack by a a process  known as smarvtd , this process replicate and ultilize the memory . i was unable to find where this process originated, so for fresh rhel7 install just looking a tool probably to reduce this kind of attack.

Comment: You could try asking in http://security.stackexchange.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com